# how to get page title in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

i am new to ruby on rails and cucumber. actually i was trying to compare page title with text i am expecting but dont know that how to get text in ruby. in selenium we can use getText function like

```
assertEquals("ID: 1351018000", selenium.getText("//div[@id='articleInfo']/ul[1]/li[1]"));
```

can you help in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

in your layout, you can have something like this :

```
<title> <%= @title %></title>
```

and everywhere in your application you can specify the title using the @title variable. So you won't need to search for the title. Once you are specifying the title you can compare it with a test string.

i hope it will help you.

Comment: i want to assert that the same text is apperaing  on the page , thats why i am trying to get the text by using xpath. can you tell me how can i use the above command in cucumber with ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

```
 response.to_s.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1]   will give u title of the page
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but how can i use this in above command. i mean its there any way to get the text with use of xpath and compare with the known result in ruby.

Comment: In your case you have to pass xpath of the title in your page to getText() method.

Comment: I am trying this ,but its giving error. assert_equal "Comment List", find(:xpath,'//div[@id='pageContainer']/div[2]/h2').getText(). and error is - C:/Workspace/cucumber-project/features/step_definitions/comment_steps.rb:135: sy ntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND ...d='pageContainer']/div[2]/h2').text ^ (SyntaxError)